# JPanel is not shown

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have some problems with the following classes:
My problem is that the JPanel doesn't get renderd on the JFrame.

Here's the source code:

MainFrame.class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    JPanel panel;

    public MainFrame() {
        setTitle("TestFrame");
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(800, 450);
        setLocation(400, 225);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new TestPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLocation(0, 0);
        panel.setSize(64, 64);
        panel.setVisible(true);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        while(true) {
            panel.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
        frame.start();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

TestPanel.class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawString("Test", 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Why does it not work properly?

Fixed. All due to bad code quality.

Comment: First of all, we add the panel like this: getContentPane().add(panel);

you can simply add it using the .add() method.

Secondly, using the intellij's debugger you can see that the start method is not working correctly.

Why have a start method that repaints you panel every 20 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've overridden the `paintComponents` method instead of `paintComponent` (without "s").

Your infinite loop `while(true)` is blocking the EDT thread which will freeze the GUI. You need to run that on a new thread or a better solution will be to use a `javax.swing.Timer` to refresh the panel.

Also, as @CoderinoJavarino has mentioned, you need to set the `y` coordinate in the `drawString(....)` call to a bigger value.

As it is mentioned in the documentation:

> The baseline of the leftmost character is at position (x, y)

You can do something like this to make sure the text isn't drawn offscreen:

```
g.drawString("Test", 0, g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
```

Comment: Okay that helps a lot, I have not done really much with swing yet. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't see your string, because your `y` parameter is too small - it defines where the bottom of the string is, and since the lowest point of string is at very top you can't see it.

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel{

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawString("Hello", 0, 10);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TestPanel());
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Also, I really don't like your `start` method, even though you are not using it yet. What you probably want to do, is let the panel implement ActionListener, and somewhere in your initialization code create a timer - `Timer t = new Timer (delay, this); t.setRepeats(true); t.start();`. This will create a new thread that will be calling `actionPerformed` method every `delay` milliseconds.

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private int red = 0;
    private Timer t;

    TestPanel() {
        t = new Timer(20, this);
        t.setRepeats(true);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color (red, 0, 0));
        g.drawString("Hello", 0, 10);

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TestPanel());
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        red = (red + 2) % 255;
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: I already used the Timer in a few other projects but I did not thought about using it in this situation, thanks :)